# Regular expression to strip out dates and values

Tags: java, regex, split

Is there a easy way to strip down to something like:

> Date: Time: Day Of Year:

from

> 2/11/2011@2:15 Date: %j time: %t Day
>   of Year: %doy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex like this...

```
 /([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4})@([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})/
```

to pull out the date and time, then calculate the day based on the date

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java there is a class that does this for you -- no need to get messy with regexp http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the Date classes?

Comment: there is, you could write a regexp like in the below answer, but why would you want to do that if this is done for you in the DateFormat classes, another option is to use strptime() in the DateTime class in java and in just about every other programming language.